# Zurb email foundation - html compiled file too big (npm run build)

Tags: email, node-modules, html-email

files are massive - font styles applied also to empty div where is not necessary.

Can I change settings on the npm run build?

example spacer applies all text styles
       `<table align="center" class="spacer float-center" style="Margin:0 auto;border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;float:none;margin:0 auto;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;padding-top:0;text-align:center;vertical-align:top;width:100%"> <tbody> <tr style="padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;padding-top:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top"> <td height="16" style="-moz-hyphens:auto;-webkit-hyphens:auto;Margin:0;border-collapse:collapse!important;color:#000;font-family:Lato,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:16px;font-weight:400;hyphens:auto;line-height:16px;margin:0;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;padding-bottom:0;padding-left:0;padding-right:0;padding-top:0;text-align:left;vertical-align:top;word-wrap:break-word"> &nbsp;</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>`

Comment: There's not enough information here to give you an answer. Try and supply your code, the exact error code, the steps you took, etc.

Comment: for example spacer is too big, no need to apply text styles on empty table or th